# isset / empty php session (if else statement) gives undefined index

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, session

I've been wanting to create a javascript function that changes the PHP session onclick. Changing the session is working to only a certain extent. When I put an if else statement using isset, it gives an error of undefined index for the second condition block (else). Searched everywhere, but could not find any leads at all. Do help me. Thanks! Here's my code.

Javascript

```
function changeLangToSpanish(){
var lang = "spanish";
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    // Reload the page
    window.location.reload();
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("POST","set_session.php?lang=" + lang,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}

function changeLangToEng(){
var lang = "english";
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    // Reload the page
    window.location.reload();
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("POST","set_session.php?lang=" + lang,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

PHP (set_session.php)

```
 <?php
    if(!isset($_SESSION)){
    session_start();
   }
   if(!isset($_SESSION['lang'])){
        $_SESSION['lang'] = "english";
   }
   else if(isset($_SESSION['lang'])){
        $_SESSION['lang'] = $_REQUEST['lang'];
   }
?>
```

HTML (for testing purposes)

```
<html>
<head>
    <?php 
    include "header.php";
    include "set_session.php";
    ?>
</head>
    <body>
        <button id = "lol" onclick = "changeLangToSpanish()">lol</button>
        <button id = "lol" onclick = "changeLangToEng()">loll</button>
        <span id = "lols"></span>

        <?php 
        if(isset($_SESSION['lang'])){

            echo '<script>
                document.getElementById("lols").innerHTML = "'.$_SESSION["lang"].'";
            </script>';
        }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

So, basically there's a HTML that shows the session in a span. The change of session is caused by the click of the 2 buttons, where the left button sets the session to "spanish" and the right to "english". It can be seen that the span shows "english" due to the initialization of the session, but when I click either of the buttons, an undefined index error pops up, indicating error in the (else) block of code. Using empty instead of isset does not solve it as well. And I'm unable to toggle between the sessions. Hope that I could get a solution. Thanks!

Comment: @Brendan Rollinson 's answer looks like the right one, but there are some other small issues you should look at. It looks like you have two buttons with the same ID - IDs should always be unique. Also it's not a big deal but probably unnecessarily verbose to say `else if (isset ($_SESSION['lang'])){` - there are only two possible states for that array element being set: yes or no. If the `if` condition fails, there's nothing *but* the `else if` condition that could be the case. Minor thing, I know, just saying.

Comment: Noted. Thanks! The minor warnings on the HTML can be ignored, as it's done simply for testing. Also, the redundancy oh the PHP. Just wanted to give a clearer picture haha. Still gives me the same error nonetheless.

Comment: Edit - Solved. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there is a potential bug in:

```
else if(isset($_SESSION['lang'])){
    $_SESSION['lang'] = $_REQUEST['lang'];
```

In particular, this code does not check whether $_REQUEST['lang'] is actually set. Maybe you mean to check that instead of checking $_SESSION['lang'] (whose value is being overwritten here)?

Comment: Edit- Misunderstood your solution. I ran a isset check on the $_REQUEST and it works like a charm. Thanks!